# model not converged when fitting SAIGE null model

Tags: gwas

When I fitted the null model in SAIGE step2 of single-variant test, it showed like following:

> seqFitNullGLMM_SPA(pheno~age+sex, phenotye, grm, trait.type="quantitative", sample.col="IID", maf=0.005, missing.rate=0.01)

```
Filtering variants:
[==================================================] 100%, completed, 10s
Fit the null model: pheno ~ age + sex + var(GRM)
    # of samples: 10,033
    # of variants: 40,739
    using 1 thread
Transform on the design matrix with QR decomposition:
    new formula: y ~ x0 + x1 + x2 - 1
Start loading SNP genotypes:
[==================================================] 100%, completed, 13s
    using 590.1M (sparse matrix)
Quantitative outcome: pheno
         mean         sd  min  max
    0.2772192 0.05953586 0.05 1.04
Inverse normal transformation on residuals with standard deviation: 0.05748074
Initial fixed-effect coefficients:
               x0           x1           x2
    -5.064086e-09 8.959324e-05 0.0003868113
Initial variance component estimates, tau:
    Sigma_E: 0.00165196, Sigma_G: 0.00165196
Iteration 1:
    tau: (0.001737522, 0.001646519)
    fixed coeff: (-5.064086e-09, 8.959324e-05, 0.0003868113)
    tau: (0, 0)
Error in seqFitNullGLMM_SPA(pheno ~ age + sex,  :
  Sigma_E = 0, model not converged!
```

Does anyone have any idea about this issue? By the way, the phenotype and covariates data are clean without any outlier. Is it related to the SNPs for grm?

I just wish to solve this "not converged" problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which SAIGE version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, it was solved. The presence of some outliers in the phenotypic data leads to the appearance of skewed distributions. It is not related to SAIGE itself.